# Auto Show and Div automatically after a set time in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have divs that automatically cycle to the next div and show its contents after every few seconds. The functionality works fine however, there seems to be a gap when the last div hides and the first div is meant to show as the underline in the corresponding link for the div has a slight delay- it should change immediately. I can't figure out why this is happening. Also, I am trying execute the function 5 seconds after the page has loaded `.delay(5000)` does not seem to work. Below is the code:

```js
var homeLinks = ['i-t', 'o-c', 'c-f', 'i-c', 'c-u'];
var currentLink = 0;
var hovered = false;

$(".home-link").hover(function() {
  hovered = true;
  $('.home-' + homeLinks[currentLink]).hide();
  $('[data-hover=' + homeLinks[currentLink] + ']').toggleClass('default-underline');
  currentLink = homeLinks.indexOf($(this).attr('data-hover'));
  $('[data-hover=' + homeLinks[currentLink] + ']').toggleClass('default-underline');
  $('.home-' + homeLinks[currentLink]).show();
}, function() {
  hovered = false;
});

var autoNavInterval = setInterval(autoNav, 3000);

function autoNav() {
  if (hovered === false) {
    $('.home-' + homeLinks[currentLink]).hide();
    $('[data-hover=' + homeLinks[currentLink] + ']').toggleClass('default-underline');
    currentLink++;
    if (currentLink >= homeLinks.length) {
      currentLink = 0;
    }
    $('[data-hover=' + homeLinks[currentLink] + ']').toggleClass('default-underline');
    $('.home-' + homeLinks[currentLink]).show();
  }
}
```

```css
.left-fill {
  background: #0000006b;
  height: 100vh;
}

.right-fill {
  background: pink;
  height: 100vh;
}

.vc_col-sm-6 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.pivot-nav {
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  text-align: left;
}

.pivot-nav li a {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.pivot-nav li a.default-underline::after,
.pivot-nav li a:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

.pivot-nav:hover a.default-underline:not(:hover)::after {
  width: 0;
}

.pivot-nav li a::after {
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  transition: width 0.3s ease 0s;
  width: 0;
}

.home-o-c,
.home-c-f,
.home-i-c,
.home-c-u {
  display: none;
}

.our-company {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  height: 50vh;
}

.cf2 {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-fill text-left wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-6">

  <div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <p class="home-i-t">TEXT One</p>
    <p class="home-o-c">TEXT One</p>
    <p class="home-c-f">TExt for C f.</p>
    <p class="home-i-c">Some more text fo i c.</p>
    <p class="home-c-u">Get in touch </p>

  </div>
</div>



<div class="home-fill right-fill text-right wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-6">

  <div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <ul class="pivot-nav">
      <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a data-hover="o-c" class="home-link" href="#" data-toggle="my-scrollspy-2">O C</a></li>
      <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a data-hover="c-f" class="home-link" href="#" data-toggle="my-scrollspy-2">C F</a></li>
      <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a data-hover="i-c" class="home-link" href="#" data-toggle="my-scrollspy-2">I C</a></li>
      <li class="pivot-nav-item" data-toggle="my-scrollspy-2"><a data-hover="c-u" class="home-link" href="#">C U</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start function 5 secounds after the page was loaded first you need to be sure that your script starts working after the document is ready. Use the basic jQuery function `$(function () { /* code executed after the document loaded */ } );`.
Than use simple javaScript function setTimeout.

The underline switched between `C U` and `O C` longer because you set the currentLink value to 0 after you iterate through every element in the array `homeLinks` and the 0 element would be an a with data-hover="i-t" which doesn't exist. You can remove the first string from the array or create an element in the list or set the currentLink value to 1 after you reach the homeLinks value with currentLink.

I fixed your script code to do exactly what you described with as few changes as possible:

```
$(function () {

  var homeLinks = ['i-t', 'o-c', 'c-f', 'i-c', 'c-u'];
  var currentLink = 0;
  var hovered = false;

  $(".home-link").hover(function () {
    hovered = true;
    $('.home-' + homeLinks[currentLink]).hide();
    $('[data-hover=' + homeLinks[currentLink] + ']').toggleClass('default-underline');
    currentLink = homeLinks.indexOf($(this).attr('data-hover'));
    $('[data-hover=' + homeLinks[currentLink] + ']').toggleClass('default-underline');
    $('.home-' + homeLinks[currentLink]).show();
  }, function (event) {
    hovered = false;
    currentLink = 0;
    $('.wpb_wrapper p').hide();
    $(event.target).toggleClass('default-underline');
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    var autoNavInterval = setInterval(autoNav, 1000);
  }, 1000);


  function autoNav() {

    if (hovered === false) {
      $('.home-' + homeLinks[currentLink]).hide();
      $('[data-hover=' + homeLinks[currentLink] + ']').toggleClass('default-underline');
      currentLink++;
      if (currentLink >= homeLinks.length) {
        currentLink = 1;
      }
      $('[data-hover=' + homeLinks[currentLink] + ']').toggleClass('default-underline');
      $('.home-' + homeLinks[currentLink]).show();
    }
    else {
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: @thanks very much. This works fine. Would it be possible to reset the autoNav function such that it a link is hovered over and then hovered out the autoNav starts from the first link?

Comment: I eddited the snippet code to serve this feature as well. I changed the handlerOut function to reset the state of the navigation.